# Find shortest path between two points without spatial database

Tags: postgis, route, shortest-path

I have an an certain area contains less than 200 roads(polylines), and I need to calculate a shortest path between two specified points inside the area.

I know maybe I can use the `pgroute` in postgis to do the calculation, however I wonder if there is an alternative to use common database like mysql instead of spatial database since the dataset is not large enough?

Comment: I don't think MySQL supports shortest-path algorithms. However, it is pretty straightforward to implement Djikstra's algorithm, here is [a Python solution](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/119466-dijkstras-algorithm-for-shortest-paths/), if you want to avoid pgrouting.

Comment: How are you storing polylines without a spatial database? Why use the postgis tag if you wish a mysql solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you load your data into qgis you can find the shortest path with this plugin: http://docs.qgis.org/1.8/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_road_graph.html

I don't know what is your source dataset, but into qgis you can import many of different gis file formats and also you can connect to spatial databases.